# Calculate Maintainer's Workload （find who merge the patch during integration process）

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I am working on 'the workload of the Linux Kernel maintainers'.  Could you please help me with the following questions. Thank you very much.

1. We know that the Linux kernel development uses the hierarchy-liked structure. A commit that appears in the mainline repository goes through a series processes, including reviewing and integration. In the integration, this commit flows from one maintainer to another maintainer. I want to calculate the workload of maintainers in the integration process. **Therefore, I need the information that who integrate (merge) this commit before it appears in the  mainline repository.** Do you have any good ideas or suggestions?
2. Could I use the tag **sign-off** to identify the maintainers of this commit?